# Python: "smooth" the discrete list of data

Tags: python, pandas, filter, smoothing

I need to "smooth" (or filter - not sure which term is more correct in this case) the list of discrete set of data based on the continuous occurance of each code.

For example I have the following dataset:

```
CodeVals= ['A','A','B','B','A','C','A','B','C','B']
```

I set the continuous duration of code appearance as, for example, not less than 3, then get the following:

```
Filtered_CodeVals = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B']
```

That means, that all single and twin values will be replaced with the neighbours, who have higher occurance. All continuous series of 3 or more values, will remain unchanged.

I appreciate your help with this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps, there should be sliding window, which will check the longest occurances before and after, to choose between them.
Codes "A", "B", "C" etc. are the outputs of some analyses applied to variable data. That's why they can have additional noise, and short occurances of certain code should be interpreted as unreliable, and changed to the neigbhor reliable occurances of different code.